# What is the difference between an easyb story and specification?

Tags: groovy, bdd, easyb

I've been trying out the easyb BDD framework for about a day and a half and I'm not sure I understand the difference between a story and a specification(besides the syntax).  A story uses the given, when, then syntax and a scenario uses the description, it, it... syntax.

Besides the syntax is there a difference between the two?

Is using one format over the other better - or is it just a 'use what you like' kind of thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both are equally powerful. Stories are easyb's original way of defining behavior driven tests, whereas specifications were added later to copy the specification style of RSpec which is the BDD framework for Ruby. So in the end, it's just a matter of taste.